# How to get URL of the tabs in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, python, bash, shell, scripting

Is there a way to get URL of the tabs in a web browser like Chrome, Firefox, etc.

I've tried selenium but that only worked with new windows created from the code and has no way of interacting with existing windows?

more clarification: is there a way that if a chrome is open with 3 tabs of 
google.com, yahoo.com, facebook.com. is there a way to extract that information without the use of a plugin?

Can be in any language, I haven't found a way to do it yet!

Thanks!

Comment: Chrome on OS X: https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli (it uses Scripting Bridge; other browsers might not expose a scriptable API via AppleScript). Don't know about other OSes and browsers.

Comment: Oh, by the way, if you are on OS X, then Safari also has a scriptable API (Script Editor->Window->Library->Safari for docs), but I don't know any readily available tool like `chrome-cli` linked above. I just checked and Firefox doesn't have a comparable API, so no luck there.

Answer (score 2):

From JavaScript/Selenium - No, that is not possible. It would pose a big security problem if any web page would be allowed to know your browsing history of other tabs and across different domains.

Imagine an advertisement page tracking your complete history - how would you, as a browser user, know?

---

From a desktop scripting/programming language, you could (in theory) read all tab urls by script-clicking the tab in question (or sending ctrl+) and reading the content of the address bar.

Comment: I don't think they are looking to do this from a web page, but from desktop scripting.

Comment: True, I focused on the javascript/selenium part. will edit to clarify. thanks!

Comment: If I made a chrome extension for this. Would it be possible to possibly run that chrome plugin using a desktop script

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this a while ago (so I may have forgotten some of the details). I think there's a security risk in pulling the content of URL bars. Something between cross site scripting and phishing. The browser doesn't allow it. The way around that is to create a browser extension or plugin so your script operates a level higher and can 'see' the URL bars.

The conclusion I arrived at was that I had to make a Chrome extension and use their upgraded iframe tag called webview in order to achieve what I wanted.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview

But the solution is essentially making your own browser. If you think about it that makes sense. Pulling the URL is what the bookmark option does in your browser.